# Implementing revisions in an entity

Tags: entities

I'm in the process of building an entity that extends DrupalDefaultEntityController, and I have some questions about the uses of the revisions mechanism, namely if I need to duplicate all the fields inside the base table within it, and what concerns there are for fieldable entities that extend the DrupalDefaultEntityController, and how to implement those as well.

For example, the base table would contain the following fields:

- Primary ID (int, serial)
- Title (varchar)
- Bodytext (text)
- Date Created (int for Unix timestamp)
- Date Modified (int for Unix timestamp)
- Type (varchar)
- Revision ID (int)

Comment: Just FYI, Entity API module does not support revisioning yet.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll revise the question to apply to entities in general.